Save as HAR file for huge content +1Gb
I successfully exported HAR files of approximately 650 MB using Firefox 132.0.1 on macOS. However, I want to export around 1.2 GB in a single HAR file.
When the content is too large, Firefox simply writes a 0-byte file to disk without displaying any errors.
Is anyone aware of ways to overcome these limitations, such as using another browser, adjusting about:config, or utilizing add-ons?

Firefox does not apply a hard limit at the size of a HAR file.

What's limiting HAR file export then ? I had plenty of RAM/disk/cpu available

When you save a HAR file the devtools code builds an object with the related antries from the network monitor, converts it to a string with JSON.strngify and saves the result to a file. In Firefox a JavaScript string cannot be larger than 2GB, I don't know how you have determined that the HAR file you want to save would be around 1.2GB but if that's the size of the binary data you expect to be captured, keep in mind that they are encoded to text with an overhead of 33%.

2Gb string is already quite a lot ;) thanks
